# Add audio file to custom iOs keyboard

Tags: ios8

I am trying to create a custom keyboard which should enable users to send audio files by sms by tapping to specific keys on the keyboard. My question is whether this is possible or if I have to send a link to the corresponding audio file (e.g. in soundcloud) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to copy an audio file to the clipboard and have it send as an audio MMS attachment via iMessage. The only keyboard I know of which provides an example of sending audio attachments is called [Quackey](http://quackey.cc/).